# how to delete SSID data from Debian wifi interface?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, ifconfig, wpa-supplicant

I have Debian distribution and when I want to reset the WIFI connection I run the following command:

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
```

and I also delete the `wpasupplicant.conf` file but when starting the network service again I get connected to the last SSID I was connected to, how can I delete these data and not auto connect to that WIFI SSID?

thanks.

Comment: what is the path you used to find the wpa-supplicant file ? can you post the content of this file ? and did you restart the network service ?

Comment: /etc/wpasupplicant.conf

Comment: did you restart the service ? sudo service networking restart, can you post the current wpa_supplicant file ?

Comment: the file is deleted then the service is restarted.

Comment: so, how it guesses the ssid/password combination of the WPA_suppl file doesnt contain them ?

Comment: Can you post the wpa_suppl file ?

Comment: network={
        scan_ssid=1
        ssid="Main"
        psk=2eb6f5dc1e87b7f7c5b542b1895cd14efcea7902de3963534caa08f0140144e1
}

Comment: delete the network= ******************** section from the file, save it (root) and restart the service.

Comment: I think although i delete the file there is another place holding this data, maybe some other module in the system.

Comment: again the file was deleted using the rm command and after that restarting the network service and this didn't help.

Comment: *again* I didn't say delete, I said, **EDIT** the file.. then SAVE then restart.. deleting it may lead the system to restore it thinking it was an error.

Comment: didn't work! I did that earlier

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to edit the existing connections by modifying the files in this directory.

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

It's where you can find all the existing data from your existing connections (wired and wireless). delete what you need it forget from there (you obviously need root privileges)

edit : ince you are using a lite debian dist, you dont have the NetworkManager.
Assuming that you deleted the targeted network from the wpa_supplicant.conf file, you have to save changes, so try to restart the service by using :

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Comment: I don't have this on my system,I get this message: cat: /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/: No such file or directory

Comment: are you using root privileges ?  a normal user cannot read them (neither delete them)

Comment: yes , it is lite dist of debian.

Comment: Mint (xfce 17.x) doesn't have anything in that folder either (though it exists)

Comment: have it my ubuntu system, will double check on my roommate debian desktop home..

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using `wpasupplicant`, you can modify the network list with `wpa_cli` (the command line interface). The network list is the list of networks it will automatically connect to, initialized from `wpasupplicant.conf`, but kept in memory as long as the demon is active. Deleting or modifying `wpasupplicant.conf` shouldn't be necessary.

From the output of `wpa_cli help`:

```
list_networks = list configured networks
select_network <network id> = select a network (disable others)
enable_network <network id> = enable a network
disable_network <network id> = disable a network
add_network = add a network
remove_network <network id> = remove a network
```

You didn't explain *why* you want to delete the SSID, but it's probably enough to just disable it.

**Edit**:

Your network list only contains one SSID (unless you somehow added more), so it's enough to only disable this one.

You may have to add something like

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
```

to your `wpa_supplicant.conf`. This is for Debian out of the box, check with `ll /var/run/wpa_supplicant` that this is the right path and group.

Comment: I want to disable every SSID to repvent auto-connect when starting the service again.

Comment: when trying this command I get this: Failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open: No such file or directory

Comment: So is `wpa_supplicant` running at all? Check with `ps axu | grep wpa`.

Comment: how can I restart the deamon in order to delete them from the memory also?!

Comment: Don't restart the demon: Do it the proper way.

Comment: no it is not running, I need to delete all data for all SSIDs

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to restart or at least reload the wpa-supplicant Daemon, so that it realizes the new/empty config.

Obviosly the same is nessesary for NetworkManager if it is installed and enabled.

```
sudo systemctl restart wpa-supplicant.service
```

If the network is unencrypted the device will reconnect to it even without wpa-supplicant running as soon as the interface is up again.
You can check if the ESSID is still set on the device using:

```
iwconfig wlan0
```

and set it to something different if you want:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid SomethingElse
```

Comment: I also tried you answer but that didn't work also!